# When will Travel SE be available for querying at data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, graduation, data-explorer

I just tried some queries on http://data.stackexchange.com, and noticed that despite graduation, Travel SE database cannot be searched yet.

Any idea when that will be possible?

Comment: Yes and are we guaranteed to be in the next data dump?

Comment: If you don't know about the data dumps, they're [mentioned in the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) occasionally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I just tried again, and now you can select "Travel Answers" or "Travel Answers Meta". Yay.

[image]

Comment: If you've new to data.SE, take a look at the [top queries by others](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries). To try it out, and as I couldn't quickly find a ready-made one, I wrote a simple query for finding your [most upvoted comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/92252/my-top-comments).

Answer (score 1):

I had never heard of this part of Stack Exchange, but it still works.

But with the amount of information on the site it might take a few tries till you find some useful results.

It is not self explanatory what will give enough results.